# compile FreeType with cmake when Visual Community installed

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2022

I try to compile FreeType project on Windows10 OS used `cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2022" C:\freetype-2.11.0`
command. but get the error:

> CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:100 (cmake_minimum_required):
> Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of CMake.
>
> Update the VERSION argument  value or use a ... suffix to tell that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:149 (project):
> Generator
>
> Visual Studio 16 2019
>
> could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

This is after I try `cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" C:\freetype-2.11.0` and get the same error.

Any suggestions?

I already try
`cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" C:\freetype-2.11.0`
`cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2022" C:\freetype-2.11.0`